# Multiple cursors at once functionality, just as in the Visual Studio Code but in every Windows application?

Tags: autohotkey, visual-studio-code, python3, autoit

Was wondering if this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics can be implemented with WinApi or by DLL calls using something such as https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm or Python?

I'd want this functionality in every text editor/browser.

Comment: You're asking what? Whether we can implement an application feature OS-wide, or in other apps that haven't been coded to support this function? What have you tried so far? Do you know how it was written into VS Code? This isn't a free major development site, and it sounds like that's what you're asking.

Comment: Short answer: likely not.